# Pass by name implementation in C

Tags: c, parameter-passing, thunk, callbyname, pass-by-name

How can I calculate the value of the arithmetic expression ^2 + 3i − 1 that is dependent on the index i **by using pass-by-name mechanism in C language**

9
∑ i^2 + 3i − 1
=0

through a call to a sum procedure with argument(s) passed by name

Pass by name examples written in C could also help me

Comment: This is not a good question! Please re-format it and ask specifics. Do not post links to pictures. Show us that you actually attempted the problem, then come back and ask!

Comment: Everything @Developer said. You can find a guide on how to ask questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There's no pass by name in C, so you cannot do that.

Comment: I know that C does not working with pass by name mehanism, but pass-by-name could be written in C. I did some research and there are two ways to do that  1) with macro's  2) by using thunk's    But I couldn't understand working logic of thunk's in C

Comment: "pass-by-name could be written in C" Macros use pass-by-name indeed. They are not functions but they are the closest thing you can get. There are no thunks in C. You might be able to write a thunk in assembly and call it from C, but that would be "using pass-by-name mechanism in the assembly language".

Comment: Could you give me a small function as an example about pass-by-name mechanism in assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done such a solution as following it works but I am not sure whether it works with pass-by-name or not,
Could you comment my solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;
typedef int* (*intThunk)(void);
int* vSubiThunk(void){ return &i; }

int sum(intThunk i){
    return (*i())* (*i()) + (*i() * 3) - 1 ;
}

int main(void){
    int total = 0;
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
        total += sum(vSubiThunk);

    printf("%d \n",total);
}
```

Comment: It gives right calculation answer but ı am not sure about pass-by-name mechanism

Answer (score 2):

There are two completely different topics here:

- (1) You want to learn C. In C you always pass a value, but that value *may* be a pointer, which in effect works like pass-by-reference.
- (2) you want to calculate that summation.

You *could* use (1) to solve (2) but it is not a good way to do it.

You *could* use (2) as an example to learn (1).

But it should be very clear that (1) and (2) are not the same thing.

- This is how you pass a value to a function in C: `void f(int i); ... f(123);`
- This is how you pass a pointer to a function in C: `void f(int* i); ... int i=123; f(&i);`

This is the typical way you would calculate the sum in C:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<=9; ++i)
    sum += 2 + 3*i - 1;
// now sum contains the sum
```

If for some reason (e.g. homework requirement?) you want to pass a pointer to calculate the sum then:

```
void f(int* psum, int i) {
    *psum += 2 + 3*i - 1;
}
...
int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<=9; ++i)
    f(&sum, i);
```

Comment: Pass by name and pass by reference are totally different.

Comment: OP is new to this, I assume he does not mean the p-by-name **you** are thinking of. It is almost certain that the confusion he experiences is exactly what i defuse in my answer.

Comment: u may confuse the OP with your C++ syntax ... `int& sum`

Comment: As we can see from the comments, he means exactly what he says.

Comment: I am not sure. He sounds like someone who is just typing "pass by name" into a search engine. But if you are right, then you should write up an answer and if he tells me, then i will delete this answer.

Comment: The question is "how to calculate a sum using pass by name in C". There's no pass by name in C, so there's no answer I can write.